# Some troubles with css width for div with marquee element

Tags: css

ive such css:

```
div.partnersheader{
    width:930px;
    height:27px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #030304;
    font-family:Bebas;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:15pt;
    padding:3px 0px 0px 10px;
}

div.partnerscontent{
    width:100%;
    height:127px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:15pt;
    padding:3px 0px 0px 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div.partnerscontent ul{
    list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; overflow:hidden; width:100%;
}

div.partnerscontent li{
    float:left; margin-left:20px;
}

div.partnerscontent li img{
    filter: url(../sources/grayscale.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
     -moz-transition:all 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

div.partnerscontent li img:hover{
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

the html is

```
    <div class="partners">
            <div class="partnersheader">
                Partnerzy
            </div>
            <div class="partnerscontent">
                <ul>
                <marquee onMouseOver="this.stop()" onMouseOut="this.start()">

<li>
<a href="http://www.cs-kontener.pl" target=_blank><img src="images/ck.png" border="0"  /></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Zajeb.Basem?fref=ts" target=_blank><img src="images/zb.png" border="0"  /></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pompeczkamp3" target=_blank><img src="images/pmp3.png" /></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/PozitiveSound" target=_blank><img src="images/pozitiw.png" /></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="http://www.club-sound.pl/" target=_blank><img src="images/clubsound.png" /></a>
</li>               </marquee>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and in partnerscontent li are placed images with marquee effect, and i can see only 3 images and rest go to line  under that 3 but i want them all to be in 1 line like:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Now its like

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

i think its sth with width but i cant find way out, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add up the widths of the `LI`s and then set the width of your `UL` accordingly (in pixels. 100% is not the answer). The container for the UL needs to have `overflow:hidden` if your list is wider than the container.

This is my best guess since you haven't shown your HTML.

Comment: if i put it in pixels there will be for example every element is 1px width and ul is 10px width ive got 3 elements in ul and ive 7px unused